# PHP-like Substring Function for C

Tags: php, c, substring

I've been working on creating string (char*) manipulation functions in C and my latest one is a PHP-like substring function. I am posting so that others can benefit from it and I would be grateful for any suggestions for improving the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the PHP substring function in C.

```
char *substr(char *str, int start, int num)
{
    //find string length
    int len = sj_strlen(str);

    char *result;

    //Return "" if start is longer than str
    if(start > len || (start*-1) > len)
    {
        result = malloc(1);
        *result = '\0';
        return result;
    }

    //Setting pointer to appropriate position
    if(start >= 0)
    {
        str += start;
    }
    else
    {
        str += (len+start);
    }

    //Allocate space for returned substring
    result = malloc(num+1);
    char *ptr = result;

    //Adding characters to the result
    while(num > 0 && *str)
    {
        *ptr++ = *str++;
        num--;
    }

    //Terminating character
    *ptr = '\0';

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "Hello, world!";
    printf("%s\n",substr(str,-10,2)); //outputs lo
   printf("%s",substr(str,7,5)); //outputs world
}
```

Comment: isn't `memcpy()` a better option than looping through the each character?

Comment: Might want to check if start > len. And str == 0. And return value of malloc.

Comment: Now you have return with "" and another from malloc(). If the user tries to free() the "" result that will not be good. Also, need to cope with start < -len. Maybe use if(abs(start) > len) return strdup("");

Comment: True, I was not thinking about the problem that would occur if free() were called. But I think that I fixed the second problem. How would you solve the `free("")` problem? Would you malloc the empty string?

Comment: Yes. strdup("") is the same as char *p = malloc(1); *p = 0;